# Can any one explain E,H plane definitions?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory

[image]

I read in some text books that

1. E-plane is formed by taking constant azimuth angle  and scanning elevation angle from -90:90.
2. H-plane is formed by taking a plane perpendicular to E-plane.

What is the meaning of taking a plane perpendicular to E-plane?? Is it to take constant elevation angle  and scan azimuth angle from -90:90?

Comment: Please, share with us the text book where you found this information.

Comment: Harry L. Van Trees - Optimum Array Processing (Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory, Part IV) (2002).PageNo:242.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to this site! That seems to be a [well-respected](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&client=tablet-android-samsung&sa=X&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQioTXVHMpzv8wGaFYiEAcLIo5VeA:1575488293492&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:%22Harry+L.+Van+Trees%22&ved=0ahUKEwjW19Kg35zmAhUiiOAKHc39CqwQ9AgISTAE&biw=768&bih=1024&dpr=1), scholarly book. I can't seem to find the book where he says that, but could it be that he says something along the lines of what [Marcus](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/15733/8717) said?

Comment: I searched other editions of this book (since the 2002 edition is not available to view on [books.google.com](http://books.google.com), and I couldn't find *E-plane*. Could you please edit your question and post a photo of that page? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this page seems to have nothing to do with E- or H-Planes. Could you explain, @kartheek?

Comment: In the high-lighted section elevation plane means E-plane at constant azimuth angle.And plane perpendicular to elevation plane is H-plane at constant elevation angle.

Answer (score 4):

Those definition are false.

The E-plane is defined as the plane in which the E-field varies over time. The H-plane is the plane in which the H-field varies over time.

There's nothing more to it.

Logically, the definition of planes only makes sense for linearly polarized antennas.

In isotropic (meaning: behaving the same from every angle) media (e.g., air), the H-plane is always perpendicular to the E-plane. *Perpendicular* is when two planes are at a right angle to each other.

Whether the E-plane is in azimuth or elevation or somewhere in between depends on the direction of polarization of the antenna.

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G ooops, yes.

Comment: He has included the page in question. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MikeWaters not really – that page nowhere mentions an E- or H-Plane.